# Locked formula moves when data is cleared - Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that clears old data from sheet2 in a Spreadsheet.  On sheet1 there is a formula, `=sumif(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$286,A4,Sheet2!$G$2:$G$286)`, that moves `$D$2` to `$D$3` and so on, whenever the connected form is submitted with new data.  How can I stop the locked formula from changing after clearing and adding new data?

Below is the code in my script that resets sheet2.

```
function reset(sheet, data) {
    var newData = new Array();         
    newData.push(data[0]);
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    sheet.deleteRows(2, lastRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?rd=1) referencing.

`=SUMIF(INDIRECT("Sheet2!$D$2:$D$286"),A4,INDIRECT("Sheet2!$G$2:$G$286"))`

or alternatively, you might be able to get away with using whole column references (depending on what's in the other rows):

`=SUMIF(Sheet2!D:D,A4,Sheet2!G:G)`

Comment: I tried the second option.  I'll let you know how it works. Thanks!